# OpenXML Property to Indent Nested List

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

I created a bullet list with OpenXML. However, I can't figure out how to enable indentation when tab is pressed on a bullet.

Here is the code snippet to create bullet rows:

```
var abstractLevel1 = new Level(new NumberingFormat() {Val = NumberFormatValues.Bullet}, new LevelText() {Val = "●"}) {LevelIndex = 0};
        var abstractLevel2 = new Level(new NumberingFormat() {Val = NumberFormatValues.Bullet}, new LevelText() {Val = "○"}) {LevelIndex = 1};
        var abstractLevel3 = new Level(new NumberingFormat() {Val = NumberFormatValues.Bullet}, new LevelText() {Val = "■"}) {LevelIndex = 2};


var abstractNum1 = new AbstractNum(abstractLevel1, abstractLevel2, abstractLevel3) {AbstractNumberId = abstractNumberId};
```

In the created document, when I try to create a sub/nested bullet by hitting tab, it results in the following:

> 

```
     ● Apples
  ○    Green Apples
     ● Pears
```

The bullet type changes as I expect but the indentation is wrong for Green Apples.

I took a document that has a working bullet list and converted it to an XML. Here is the section for the bullet list style:

```
<text:list-style style:name="WWNum1">
  <text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="1" text:style-name="ListLabel_20_1" style:num-suffix="●" text:bullet-char="●">
   <style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment">
    <style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="0.5in"/>
  </style:list-level-properties>
  </text:list-level-style-bullet>
  <text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="2" text:style-name="ListLabel_20_2" style:num-suffix="○" text:bullet-char="○">
   <style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment">
    <style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="1in"/>
   </style:list-level-properties>
  </text:list-level-style-bullet>
  <text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="3" text:style-name="ListLabel_20_3" style:num-suffix="■" text:bullet-char="■">
   <style:list-level-properties text:list-level-position-and-space-mode="label-alignment">
    <style:list-level-label-alignment text:label-followed-by="listtab" fo:text-indent="-0.25in" fo:margin-left="1.5in"/>
   </style:list-level-properties>
```

Notice the properties `fo:text-indent` and `fo:margin-left`. These properties are missing in the XML document produced by my code. I suspect this is the reason why sub/nested bullets are not being indented as shown in the example above. I searched through the OpenXML documentation and I could not find any information on these 2 properties. Which OpenXML class is responsible for those properties? I'm sure I need to add another argument when I instantiate a `Level` class but I could not figure out from the doc what it needs to be. Any ideas?

So far I've tried playing around with the `ParagraphStyleIdInLevel` and `Indentation` classes to no success.